# My phone was stolen and ended up in a prison,

Tags: sms, recovery-mode, calls, email, imei

My cell phone was stolen ended up in a prison, I have my email for Gmail, but they have changed my password and my security questions, I had to change my phone number because when I reported it stolen to my phone carrier and had it transferred to another phone they kept getting back in because they knew my phone number so I just had to change the phone number. I was wondering if I have the IMEI number for the phone can I access all my information?

Comment: No the IMEI does not allow you to access anything as a end user. There are some services that might allow to get the position of the phone (ab)using the SS7 network and some malicious actors may be able to redirect SMS messages also using SS7 but that all has nothing to do with Andorid.

Comment: Next time protect your phone using a 6 digit PIN, and also make sure the used passwords for Google and other services can not be guessed.